# Append a 2D array while looping through it

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to store certain values in a 2D array. In the below code. I want `sT` to be `total`. When the inner loop runs the values to be stored in rows and then next column when the outer loop increment happens.

```
class pricing_lookback:
  def __init__(self,spot,rate,sigma,time,sims,steps):
    self.spot = spot
    self.rate = rate
    self.sigma = sigma
    self.time = time
    self.sims = sims
    self.steps = steps
    self.dt = self.time/self.steps

  def call_floatingstrike(self):

      simulationS = np.array([])
      simulationSt = np.array([])
      call2 = np.array([])
      total = np.empty(shape=[self.steps, self.sims])
      for j in range(self.sims):
          sT = self.spot
          pathwiseminS = np.array([])
          for i in range(self.steps):
              phi= np.random.normal()
              sT *= np.exp((self.rate-0.5*self.sigma*self.sigma)*self.dt + self.sigma*phi*np.sqrt(self.dt))
              pathwiseminS = np.append(pathwiseminS, sT)
              np.append(total,[[j,sT]])###This should store values in rows of j column
              #print (pathwiseminS)
          #tst1 = np.append(tst1, pathwiseminS[1])
          call2 = np.append(call2, max(pathwiseminS[self.steps-1]-self.spot,0))
          #print (pathwiseminS[self.steps-1])
          #print(call2)
          simulationSt = np.append(simulationSt,pathwiseminS[self.steps-1])
          simulationS =  np.append(simulationS,min(pathwiseminS))
      call = max(np.average(simulationSt) - np.average(simulationS),0)
      return call, total#,call2,
```

Comment: The `x=np.array([])` `x=np.append(x,...)` approach is bad - inefficient and hard to get right.  Collect values in lists (or a list of lists).  List append is faster.

Comment: @hpaulj memory optimisation is the last stage. First I want to know how to append a 2D array

Comment: I'm not talking about memory optimization.  It's about getting the code right.   What errors are you getting?  `np.append` is a poorly named front-end to `np.concatenate`.  `concatenate` requires matching dimensions.  That includes the initial array, the one(s) you create with `np.array([])` and `np.empty(...)`.  Neither is a substitute for the list `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of what I think you are trying to do:

```
for i in range(5):
    row = np.random.rand(5,)
    if i == 0:
        my_array = row
    else:
        my_array = np.vstack((my_array, row))
    print(row)
```

However, this is not very efficient with memory, especially if you are dealing with large arrays, as this has to allocate new memory on every loop. It would be much better to preallocate an empty array and then populate it if possible.

To answer the question of how to append a column, it would be something like this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(5, 4)
column_to_append = np.random.rand(5,)
np.insert(x, x.shape[1], column_to_append, axis=1)
```

Again, this is not memory efficient and should be avoided whenever possible. Preallocation is much better.

Comment: I like that idea of appending a column but I don't know how to dot it. In the above code `pathwiseminS` can be appended to `total` everytime the inside for loop ends. 
@Wade Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: @VarunYadav see the updated answer for how to append a column.

Comment: I tired this `np.insert(pathwiseminS, pathwiseminS.shape[1], total, axis=1)` now I am getting an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` The above line is placed just above `call2 = np.append(call2, max(pathwiseminS[self.steps-1]-self.spot,0))`